# $PA \ge 1-r$ and $PB_k \ge 1-r/2^k$. Then $P (A\cap \bigcap_k B_k) \ge 1-2r$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have $PA \ge 1-r$ and $PB_k \ge 1-r/2^k$. Then why is $P (A\cap \bigcap_k B_k) \ge 1-2r$?

I know that $P \bigcap_k B_k \ge 1-r$ by taking the limits, but how do we get the probability of the two intersections to be bounded below by the sum of the lower bounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\bigcap_k B_k=C$.

We know that $P(A\cap C)=P(A)+P(C)-P(A\cup C)$, with

$P(A)\geq 1-r, P(C)\geq 1-r \ \textrm{and} \ P(A\cup C)\leq 1$.

Therefore ...